# How to pass data from one screen to another inside TabNavigator in react native

Tags: react-native, tabs, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

[image]

Hello All,I am using react-navigation v3 for navigation purposes.I have created a tab navigator called TourPackagesTab.It consists of 2 screens,InternationalToursScreen and DomesticToursScreen.

I fetch some data in InternationalToursScreen.The fetched data is also to be used in DomesticToursScreen. How do I pass the fetched data to DomesticToursScreen as it is inside tabNavigator?

Comment: you could set and get data through

    navigation.setParams()
    navigation.getParam()

Answer (score 1):

Hi there you can send data through `onPress` events via params, for example:

```
  onPress={() => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Screen2', {
      data1: item.data1,
      data2: item.data2,
    });
  }}
```

Then on `Screen2` you access it like this:

```
const data = this.props.navigation.state.params;
<Text>{data.data1}</Text>
```

Also TabNavigators have an `onPress` event that you can use to perform functions, see more [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/tab-navigator.html#tabbaronpress)

Comment: Hello Sara, I dont have any buttons in screen 1. So now how do I perform this onpress function and pass the data?

Comment: Hi @LogeshSelva -- how are you getting to the second screen? Sounds like you might need to use redux in that case; once you fetch the data for your first screen, you can put it in the store so that you can access it in the second screen.

Comment: Hello Sara, Thanks for the comments, btw I just swipe right to got to next tab and How do I put data in store and access it in second screen using redux? It would be greatful if u share some piece of code, as there is no clear docs regarding above in redux.Pls consider and help!

Comment: Hi @LogeshSelva so it would be something like, as soon as you receive the data you're fetching on Tab1, you add it to your Redux store with an action `this.props.addData`, once you get to Tab2 you can _read_ the data like `this.props.addedData` -- if you want to read more about how to set up Redux: https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started then to read from the store, use `react-redux`: https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate

Answer (score 0):

You can send data like this:

```
    onPress={() => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Screen2', {
      data1: item.data1,
      data2: item.data2,
    });
  }}
```

And on the next screen you have to do this:

```
const data1 = this.props.navigation.getParam('data1');
const data2 = this.props.navigation.getParam('data2');
```